# Why does Python's SysLogHandler require an address?

Tags: python, logging, python-3.4, syslog

This code logs to syslog using the `syslog` module:

```
import syslog

syslog.syslog(syslog.LOG_ERR, 'a')
```

And here's the equivalent code using the `logging` module:

```
import logging
from logging.handlers import SysLogHandler

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.addHandler(SysLogHandler(address='/dev/log'))
logger.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
logger.error('a')
```

If I leave out the `address` parameter in the second snippet, it doesn't do anything. Why does the `logging` version require me to specify an address, when the `syslog` module can figure it out on its own?

I'd rather not have to specify this path, since it's platform-dependent. Am I going to have to write my own version of SysLogHandler that delegates to the `syslog` module?

Comment: Re. your comment: If by "this one" you mean "use the syslog.syslog API", no - because the goal of that logging handler is not to use that specific API. It's to allow logging to local *or* remote syslog servers using the same API. So if you need to use the syslog.syslog API, you will have to write your own handler, but that seems fair enough given that this is (apparently) not that common a need (only once before has it come up in the dozen years since logging was added to Python).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `syslog.syslog` API allows you to send events to the system logger on the local machine only, whereas by specifying an address in Python logging you can log not only to the local machine but also a remote `syslog` server. So, the logging approach covers a wider set of circumstances than `syslog.syslog` does. Also note that on some platforms / in some environments, `syslog.syslog` was not always thread-safe (in the past), because the underlying system call API was not thread-safe in those environments. This may not be the case any longer, but it's best to check the documentation for `syslog` on your platform. For more background, see [this Python issue](https://bugs.python.org/issue1711603).

Also, you can log to a `syslog` server from Windows machines too, using the logging API (The `syslog` module is not available on Windows).

Comment: "the logging approach covers a wider set of circumstances" - but not this one?

Comment: Okay, so the answer to my question is: Because the syslog module logs via a system call, and the log handler doesn't have that option because the maintainer chose not to include it. Thanks for finding that issue.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

> Note that if your server is not listening on UDP port 514, SysLogHandler may appear not to work.

Have you verified that your syslog is listening to the default port (514) used by `SysLogHandler`? If they aren't the same, then you will need to provide the specific port number or path to a log to use.

See: https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html#sysloghandler

Comment: Including the address is what makes the difference, not the port. (Apologies, I edited the question heavily, probably after you started answering.)

Comment: To double check we're on the same page, the 'address' keyword parameter is where the (host, port) or file path is specified.

Comment: I'm not sure why any of this is relevant, though. When I don't specify any configuration at all, shouldn't the defaults for SysLogHandler just call `syslog.syslog(...)` and do whatever that does?